# Angular2 Local variable values for show/hide child element

Tags: angular

I am trying to replicate a simple collapsible menu nav bar on my site but am struggling to show menu items which have child elements and are therefore collapsable/expandable.

I have a simple `<ul>` with each `<li>` being a navigation element. Some of those have sub `<ul>`'s which should be expanded when the parent `<li>` is clicked. This really seems like quite a well used way of doing menus but I am unable to get it to work....

Current HTML:

```
<nav class="widget-body">
   <ul class="acc-menu">
      <li class="nav-separator"><span>Explore</span></li>
      <li class="hasChild" #configBtn (click)="configBtn.show"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="ti ti-settings"></i><span>Configuration</span></a>
          <ul class="acc-menu" [hidden]="configBtn.show">
              <li><a [routerLink]="['Configuration']">Gloabl settings</a>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Could anyone help - It really seems like this should be possible without involving the component.

**UPDATE**

Simply the above code does nothing. The child element is neither shown now hidden. I don't appear to be able to *spy* on the local var configBtn either as any use of {{configBtn}} causes Angular2 issues.

Quite simply I would like the child `<li>` to be shown and hidden when the parent `<li>` is clicked.

**SOLUTION**

`<li class="hasChild" #configBtn (click)="configBtn.show = !configBtn.show">
<a href="javascript:;"><i class="ti ti-settings"></i><span>Configuration</span></a>
    <ul class="acc-menu" [hidden]="configBtn.show">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Configuration']">Gloabl settings</a>
    </ul>
</li>`

Comment: My answer is only a guess because you don't explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: Try `<li class="hasChild" #configBtn (click)="configBtn.show = !configBtn.show">`

Comment: Worked :) Thanks Sasxa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need

```
[hidden]="configBtn.show ? true : null"
```

to get `hidden` removed when `configBtn.show` changes to `null` but not on `false` which only results in `hidden="false"`.

As Sasxa already mentioned

```
(click)="configBtn.show = !configBtn.show"
```

is necessary to make it work https://plnkr.co/edit/TqAO3Pqsl5NQpL7CzmmI?p=preview